# warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem when I get cell in UITableView. It cause of crash my app and show log:

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will
>   significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

And it's my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CustomCell *cell = [_theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGSize labelSize = [cell.timeLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cell.timeLabel.font}];
    CGFloat timeLabelHeight = labelSize.height;
```

It alway break and crash on line

```
CustomCell *cell = [_theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Could you help me to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

you should change the code you typed:

```
CustomCell *cell = [_theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to as following:

```
CustomCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question and under ARC what difference it makes anyway.